# Excel 2019 still displays save prompt even when the Application.EnableEvents = False

Tags: excel, vba

I tried all the different blocks of codes below but when I close the Excel, it still prompts whether to save or not.

I have the code in the Workbook BeforeClose event.
I am using excel 2019 and Windows 11

I tried this,

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

this,

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

and this,

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `I have the code in the Workbook BeforeClose event` - well, the event has already happened. It's too late to disable events now. Especially if you re-enable them immediately.

Comment: How can I do this then? Save the workbook without prompting when I close the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` is a workbook change. Hence the previous `saved` state is no longer valid. You can confirm this easily enough my doing the same thing manually. i.e. toggle calculation state after a save and attempt to close the book.

Interestingly enough, it you save one book with `Auto calc` `on` and close it. Then save another with `Auto calc` `off` and close it. The calc state will be reflected by whichever you next open. That is to say, it's saved in the `workbook` (not the `application`). Excel resolves conflicts by adopting the current state to any subsequent books opened.

This isn't new by the way. Been like that as long as I can remember. Which, unfortunately, is too long :)

Comment: So I changed the order... First I changed the calculation to `xlCalculationAutomatic` `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and then saved workbook and it worked.